# .NET Core - SerializerSettings not being applied

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

Random class

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configItem)
```

SerializerSettings are not being applied -> null values are not ignored.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you are configuring the options for middleware serialization here, not for manually serializing via `JsonConvert`. So I believe this is expected.

Comment: So I have to pass this manually to the SerializeObject method?

Comment: Yes, via the `settings` parameter.

Comment: Is there any way you know where you can globally define the serializationsettings?

Comment: Actually found something like this. I'm defining it inside the Startup method:             JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
            {
                return new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                };
            };

Comment: Good find. You should post as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside startup.cs:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => { 
    return new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
    }; 
};
```

To apply global JsonConvert settings.